# Extract text from string starting and ending by specific char

Tags: vba

I've got the code below which is extracting a string from brackets and it's ok, but now I've found out that sometimes in my string there can be more brackets with texts behind and I need to extract them too. For instance, a list or table.

e.g

```
hsus(irt)bla dsd (got)(rifk)
```

I need then: irt, got, rifk to list, how to do it?

```
Public Function extract_value(str As String) As String
dim str as string
dim openPos as integer
dim closePos as integer
dim midBit as string

str = "sometinhf(HELLO)sds"
openPos = instr (str, "(")
closePos = instr (str, ")")
midBit = mid (str, openPos+1, closePos - openPos - 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Main()

    Dim s$
    s = "hsus(irt)bla dsd (got)(rifk)"

    Debug.Print extract_value(s)

End Sub

Public Function extract_value$(s$)

    Dim returnS$
    Dim v
    v = Split(s, Chr(40))

    For Each Item In v
        If InStr(Item, Chr(41)) Then
            returnS = returnS & Chr(32) & Split(Item, ")")(0)
        End If
    Next

    extract_value = Trim$(returnS)
End Function
```

Comment: Nice, you were pretty quick. Do You know how much faster than `Mid(params)` `Split(params)` is to split a string?

Comment: @smagnan have never measured that. do you recon this is a bad approach though?

Comment: You mean using `Mid` instead of `Split`? I imagine it is really not the best approach since `Mid` is used to extract substrings ... but because I'm quite new to VBA I still dont know many functions

Comment: `Split()` splits the entire string in a Variant/String array based on the delimiter. So by using `Split()` you are already limiting the length of string the `Mid()` will have to go over to extract a substring. With `v` being only a few words (in memory) now you check if each of the words has a `)` in it. If it doesn't then you skip that word and if it does then you use Split again with a different delimiter just like edited code instead of Mid which would be slower in this case

Comment: @ me how, that was fast! :)... @smagnan, I believe `Split` should be slightly faster string operation as allocating separate strings directly in VBA is a slow process.

Comment: me how -thanks for your post anyway i got two additional question - how then can i add next extract_value(s) to some table/list because i would do this operation for many strings and i would like to store it all inside some table/list. The second question question is because sometimes between () my string can contain special characters and i would like to cut them of the string (i would like only to stay A-Z a-z 0-9 how could i do it?

Comment: @StackUser I believe that your original problem is now solved. If you have additional questions dont hesitate to [***ask a new question***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: ok heres the next question thanks to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529452/extracting-text-to-table-without-special-characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Regexp` to extract the matching strings directly

```
Sub Main()
    Dim strTest as string
    strTest = "hsus(irt)bla dsd (got)(rifk)"
    MsgBox GrabIt(strTest)
End Sub

Function GrabIt(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Dim objRegM As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "\((.*?)\)"
.Global = True
    If .test(strIn) Then
    Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)
        For Each objRegM In objRegMC
        GrabIt = GrabIt & Chr(32) & objRegM.submatches(0)
        Next
    End If
End With
End Function
```