# Extracting text to table without special characters

Tags: vba

this script is going to extract each text between () from whole string. Now i would prepare it as a function because many string will be taking under that then i would like to add each extracted words inside table/or list. Each of extracted texts between () should be without special characters which sometimes could occur inside text and i would like to cut them of the string (i would like only to stay A-Z a-z 0-9 how could i do it all?

```
Sub Main()    
    Dim s$
    s = "hsus(irt)bla dsd (got)(rifk)"    
    Debug.Print extract_value(s)    
End Sub

Public Function extract_value$(s$)    
    Dim returnS$
    Dim v
    v = Split(s, Chr(40))

    For Each Item In v
        If InStr(Item, Chr(41)) Then
            returnS = returnS & Chr(32) & Split(Item, ")")(0)
        End If
    Next

    extract_value = Trim$(returnS)
End Function
```

Comment: You can write another function that *strips* the special characters

Answer (score 1):

When parsing you can use a helper function to check for just letters and numbers using the ASCII encoding.

```
Function validChr(chr As String) as Boolean
Dim ascCode As Integer

ascCode = Asc(chr)

If ascCode >= 65 And ascCode <= 90 Then 'Uppercase
    validChr = True
ElseIf ascCode >= 97 And ascCode <= 122 Then 'Lowercase
    validChr = True
ElseIf ascCode >= 48 And ascCode <= 57 Then 'Numbers
    validChr = True
Else
    validChr = False

End Function
```

You can also look at using RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

```
This two stage `Regexp`
```

1. Converts `hsus(ir%$%^t)bla dsd (g°ot)(rifk)` to `ir%$%^t g°ot rifk`
2. In a single shot `ir%$%^t g°ot rifk`to `irt got rifk`

*test sub*

```
Sub Main()
    Dim strTest As String
    strTest = "hsus(ir%$%^t)bla dsd (g°ot)(rifk)"
    MsgBox GrabIt(strTest)
End Sub
```

*main sub*

```
Function GrabIt(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Dim objRegM As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "\((.*?)\)"
.Global = True
    If .test(strIn) Then
    Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)
        For Each objRegM In objRegMC
        GrabIt = GrabIt & Chr(32) & objRegM.submatches(0)
        Next
    End If
.Pattern = "[^\w|\s]+"
GrabIt = .Replace(GrabIt, vbNullString)
End With
End Function
```